# Bootstrap col-md-12 align button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I am trying whole the time to align button center within "col-md-12"
But I don't have solution for responsive design.
This solution must be placed by button

```
#player-list-button {
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

This solution is good, but not for responsive.
That means, when I resize browser smaller, this button stay not in the middle of col-md-12, it disappears. Must be placed by col-md-12

```
#notResponsitiv{
    margin-lef:34%;
}
```

Sorry, here is my code. My DropDown Buttom i wanna align center.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <button type="button" id="player-list-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-main-style" data-toggle="dropdown">MyItems<span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">          
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>                   
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Version 3**
Sadly it does not works.

```
#player-list-button {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

When i use 2 rows, like in following html, the button is on the left side by desktop and if i resize the window, button will disappear:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:pink">
            <h1>hello</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:pink">
            <h1>hello</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:pink">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <button type="button" id="player-list-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-main-style" data-toggle="dropdown">MyItems<span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">          
                            <li>item</li>
                            <li>item</li>
                            <li>item</li>                   
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Version 4**
[image]

Comment: Use `@media` queries for the common breakpoints.

Comment: Could you please provide a code example on for example http://jsfiddle.net?
This would make it easier to understand your problem.

Comment: Please @Roma Kap post you entire code for us.

Comment: please look on top, i have edited my post

Comment: JSfiddle or screenshot, please.

Comment: Just added picture, how should it appears. Please look on "Version 4"

Comment: Solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578853/how-to-center-buttons-in-twitter-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 0):

```
#player-list-button {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: that works, but only for the singel button.
When i place this button as drop-down menu, so it will be rendered on the left side. And when i placed it simply like button without drop-down menu, it will be placed in the middle.
I have to achieve, that the **drop-down-button and these items**  will be rendered within col-md-12 in the middle of this column, independly of resizing. 
Please look on my Post by  **Version 3** for the code-example