# Align buttons center small screen bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align my buttons to the center of the mobile screen when the screen size gets small, tried setting text-align to center but that doesn't seem to work.

It must be something with the pull left /  text right bootstrap class im trying to override, just not too sure what I am missing.

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 998px) {

    @font-face{
        font-family: 'Gotham';
        src: url("assets/fonts/Gotham-Bold.otf");
        src: url("assets/fonts/Gotham-Light.otf");
    }

    @font-face {
    font-family: "Gotham-Bold";
    src: url("assets/fonts/Gotham-Bold.otf");
    font-weight: Bold;
    }

    @font-face {
    font-family: "Gotham-Light";
    src: url("assets/fonts/Gotham-Light.otf");
    font-weight: Light;
    }

    .col-md-4.pull-left.text-right{
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
    }
.
.
.
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 pull-right text-left" >
                <div class="IMGpadding"></div><br>
                <img style="float:left" class="img-responsive" src = "assets/images/white-leaf-bg.jpg" id="frame"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 pull-left text-right" >
                <div class="h1padding"></div>
                <a style="float:right" class = "h1" href="" id="introID"><b>INTRO</b></a>

                <div class="h1padding"></div>
                <a style="float:right" class = "h1" href="" id="OnSuerfaceID"><b>ON THE</b> <span class="light">SURFACE</span></a>

                <div class="h1padding"></div>
                <a style="float:right"  href="" id="FromOilID"><b>FROM</b> <span class="light">ORE TO OIL</span></a>

                <div class="h1padding"></div>
                <a style="float:right"  href="" id="EnvImpactID"><b>ENVIRONMENTAL</b> <span class="light">CARE</span></a>

                <div class="h1padding"></div>
                <a style="float:right" class = "h1" href="" id="MoreThanGasID"><b>MUCH MORE THAN</b> <span class="light">GASOLINE</span></a>

                <div class="h1padding"></div>
                <a style="float:right" class = "h1" href="" id="OneMoreID"><b>ONE MORE</b> <span class="light">THING</span></a>

            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Current look]

Thanks in advance, I am still very much a noob at bootstrap.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center buttons in Twitter Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578853/how-to-center-buttons-in-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Comment: you need to remove the float:right in all your elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your other pages as well as. As per your requirement and code added here, I have added a working copy in codepen. Try this:
[image]

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 998px) {

    @font-face{
        font-family: 'Gotham';
        src: url("assets/fonts/Gotham-Bold.otf");
        src: url("assets/fonts/Gotham-Light.otf");
    }

    @font-face {
    font-family: "Gotham-Bold";
    src: url("assets/fonts/Gotham-Bold.otf");
    font-weight: Bold;
    }

    @font-face {
    font-family: "Gotham-Light";
    src: url("assets/fonts/Gotham-Light.otf");
    font-weight: Light;
    }

    .col-sm-4.pull-left.text-right{
        position: relative;
        text-align: right;
      width:50%;
      text-align:right;
    }
  .h1padding {
    margin-bottom:100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 pull-right text-left" >
                <div class="IMGpadding"></div><br>
                <img style="float:left" class="img-responsive" src = "assets/images/white-leaf-bg.jpg" id="frame"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 pull-left text-right" >
                <div class="h1padding"></div>
                <a class = "h1" href="" id="introID"><b>INTRO</b></a>

                <div class="h1padding"></div>
                <a class = "h1" href="" id="OnSuerfaceID"><b>ON THE</b> <span class="light">SURFACE</span></a>

                <div class="h1padding"></div>
                <a  href="" id="FromOilID"><b>FROM</b> <span class="light">ORE TO OIL</span></a>

                <div class="h1padding"></div>
                <a  href="" id="EnvImpactID"><b>ENVIRONMENTAL</b> <span class="light">CARE</span></a>

                <div class="h1padding"></div>
                <a class = "h1" href="" id="MoreThanGasID"><b>MUCH MORE THAN</b> <span class="light">GASOLINE</span></a>

                <div class="h1padding"></div>
                <a class = "h1" href="" id="OneMoreID"><b>ONE MORE</b> <span class="light">THING</span></a>

            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/nabanitadasgupta/pen/boLGem)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using bootstrap, you can use `.visible-sm`, `.visible-md` and `.visible-lg` classes. For more info: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#responsive-utilities.